# python - using BaseHTTPRequestHandler with UnixStreamServer causes exception

Tags: python, sockets, unix-socket, basehttprequesthandler

I'm trying to create a basic HTTP server bound to a Unix Domain Socket, but using a BaseHTTPRequestHandler subclass with UnixStreamServer is creating an exception that suggests they cannot work together.

Toy server.py:

```
from SocketServer import UnixStreamServer
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write("Hi!")

server = UnixStreamServer('./mysocket.sock', MyHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

I then send a request with `curl --unix-socket ./mysocket.sock http:/hello`, which results in the following exception on the server (using Python 2.7.11):

```
Exception happened during processing of request from 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 318, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 328, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "server.py", line 6, in do_GET
    self.send_response(200)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 385, in send_response
    self.log_request(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 422, in log_request
    self.requestline, str(code), str(size))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 456, in log_message
    (self.client_address[0],
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I did some digging and the issue is related to the fact that `sock.accept()` returns the empty string as the address, presumably because there's no concept of client address on UDS calls. BaseHTTPRequestHandler, however, expects one for logging (and maybe other things)

Is there a way to workaround this issue that doesn't involve monkeypatching or re-implementing BaseHTTPServer with this one small change? Is BaseHTTPRequestHandler even intended to work with UnixDataStream? Better suggestions for a lightweight UDS HTTP server in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up subclassing UnixStreamServer and overriding get_request (which is one of the TCPServer methods intended to be overridden):

```
class UnixHTTPServer(UnixStreamServer):
  def get_request(self):
    request, client_address = self.socket.accept()
    # BaseHTTPRequestHandler expects a tuple with the client address at index
    # 0, so we fake one
    if len(client_address) == 0:
      client_address = (self.server_address,)
    return (request, client_address)
```

(Note that self.server_address gives the path to the file descriptor being used for the UDS)

It's not the cleanest solution, but not the hackiest either.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BaseHTTPRequestHandler with HTTPServer.

```
import os, socket, BaseHTTPServer


class HTTPHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send(200,'Success')

    def do_POST(self):
        size = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length',0))
        body = self.rfile.read(size)
        self.send(200,'Success')

    def send(self,code,reply):
        self.client_address=('',) # avoid exception in BaseHTTPServer.py log_message()
        self.send_response(code)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(reply)


sock_file = 'socket'
try: os.remove(sock_file)
except OSError: pass
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(sock_file)
sock.listen(0)

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(sock_file,HTTPHandler,False)
server.socket = sock
server.serve_forever()

sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
sock.close()
os.remove(sock_file)
```